# What is the performance tradeoff between a hybrid app and a native app?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Has anyone ever do a quantitative analysis on this in terms of performance? I keep reading online that hybrid sacrifices user experience, but how much of it is it for a simple client facing app that uses an REST service?

What about something more computationally intensive like a game?

Comment: No real analysis here, but just my experience. Big difference is that the loading time is worse, but as lang as you need not to use thousands of rows in a time or really complex calculation / graphics, it's fine.
Even games are, but it really depends on the target device. If using a new webview, Chrome is decently able to handle graphics well if using css transitions and not relying on javascript so much.
Native offers better performance, but for a simple game it will do fine with the added benefit of being able to serve it on the web as well.
Look into Ionic 2 or Nativescript as well!!

Comment: Nativescript is a cool intermediate because it compiles to native script :)